# how to add more functionality to my hangman java code?

Tags: java

i have created this code that is a simple hangman game the code checks if the user input is a character or a string, and it swaps the underscores in the dashes array with the user input.

my question is how i add the functionality to tell the user that their input is not in the word, and how to swap if the user enters for example 2 or more consecutive letters that are in the word?

```
public class question6 {

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String secretword = "testing";

        // now we need to create an array that stores characters so that we can swap them
        // this is an array of characters that has the same length as the secret word

        char[] dashes =new  char[secretword.length()];
        // now we need to add dashes to the array

        for (int i=0; i<secretword.length(); i++){
            dashes[i]= '_' ;
        }
        // now we need to start a loop that asks the user for input until all the dashes are swapped


        // declaring variables for loop counter and steps

        int counter = 0;
        int steps =0;

        // condition remains true until the counter is the same length as the secret word to make sure we swap everything

        while (counter<secretword.length()){

            // asking for input

            System.out.print("Key in one character or your guess word: ");
                String userinput = input.nextLine();

                // if it is a character

                if (userinput.length() == 1){

                    for (int i = 0; i<secretword.length(); i++){
                        // swapping

                        if (userinput.charAt(0) == secretword.charAt(i)){

                            dashes[i] = userinput.charAt(0);
                            counter ++;
                        }
                    }    
                }

                    // swapping the whole word  

                else if (userinput.equals(secretword)){

                    for (int j=0; j<secretword.length(); j++){
                        dashes[j]= userinput.charAt(j);
                        counter = secretword.length();
                    }
                }
                steps ++;
                System.out.println(dashes);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that you overvalue empty lines.

Comment: There are interesting articles on [so] like [ask] and [mcve] in [help]. I strongly recommend them as they help to learn how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised version of your code that does what you want:

```
public class HangManGame {

    private static final int MAX_GUESSES = 10;
    private String secretword;
    private char[] dashes;
    int guessedPositions;
    int guesses;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HangManGame game = new HangManGame("testing");
        game.start();
    }

    private HangManGame(String secretword) {
        this.secretword = secretword;
        initDashes();
    }

    private void initDashes() {
        dashes = new char[secretword.length()];
        for (int i=0; i < secretword.length(); i++){
            dashes[i]= '_' ;
        }
    }

    private void start() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);            
        while (guessedPositions < secretword.length() && guesses < MAX_GUESSES) {
            System.out.println("Guess the word: " + Arrays.toString(dashes));
            guessedPositions += guess(input.nextLine());                
            guesses++;
         }
         reportEndOfGame();
     }

    private int guess(String userInput) {
        int guessedPositionsThisTurn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < userinput .length(); i++) {
            guessedPositionsThisTurn += guessLetter(userinput.charAt(0));
        }                  
        reportIfAllWrong(guessedPositionsThisTurn);
        return guessedPositionsThisTurn;
    }

    private void guessLetter(char userChar) {
        int guessedPositionsThisLetter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < secretword.length(); i++) {
            if (secretword.charAt(i) == userChar){
               dashes[i] = userChar;;
               guessedPositionsThisLetter++;
            }
        }
        return guessedPositionsThisLetter;
    }

    private void reportIfAllWrong(int guessedPositionsThisTurn) {
        if (guessedPositionsThisTurn == 0) {
            System.out.println("All letters were wrong!");
        }  
    }

    private void reportEndOfGame() {
        if (guessedPositions == secretword.length()) {
            System.out.println("Yay! You guessed the word");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You failed! Any last words?");
        } 
    }
}
```

Note that the main method creates an instance of HangMan and calls its start method to play the game. The HangMan instance has fields which store the state of the game, making it possible to reference these values from the different methods I created. Splitting the code into methods makes it more readable because the complete process is divided into logical subtasks.